# Covert a range to string values using array

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert a range of cells from integer to String. However, since I have so much data, I can't use a standard loop for ranges as it takes too long.
Instead I thought to use the array and convert the desired range(array) into string values.

This is what I tried to do by modifying my standardcode that converts range into string just instead range I would use in the below the array:

```
Sub CovertToString()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim sArray As Variant
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim cell As Variant

With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    sArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 8), .Cells(LastRow, 8))

   For Each cell In sArray
        cell = "'" & cell.Value
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, It does not work which I understand as I am not sure how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way will convert the cell formats to `Text`:

```
Sub ConvertToString()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 7)
        'Convert format to 'Text'
        .Range(.Cells(1, 8), LastCell).NumberFormat = "@"
    End With

End Sub
```

This way will copy the range to an array and add a `'` to each value before posting back to the sheet:

```
Sub ConvertToString()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim vValues() As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        'Your code is looking for last cell in column A, so offset to column H once found.
        'This is a reference to the last cell, not the row number so can be used in the range.
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 7)
        vValues = .Range(.Cells(1, 8), LastCell).Value

        'Add a ' to each value.
        For R = 1 To UBound(vValues, 1)
            vValues(R, 1) = "'" & vValues(R, 1)
        Next R

        'Paste back to sheet.
        .Range(.Cells(1, 8), LastCell) = vValues
    End With

End Sub
```

[Further reading on arrays & worksheets](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Second solution with array is perfect :) Thanks you !